# How to get sum of rows in resultset?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression, union-all

I am writing the following query in PostgreSQL:

```
select case mod(empno,2)
        when 0 then 'EVEN '
        else 'ODD  '
       end as empno, sum(sal)
from emp
group by mod(empno,2);
```

To get the output:

```
EMPNO   SUM(SAL)
EVEN       25
ODD        50
```

How should I modify the query to the output as below?

```
EMPNO   SUM(SAL)
EVEN       25
ODD        50
Total      75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `UNION ALL` like below

```
select case mod(empno,2)
when 0 then 'EVEN '
else 'ODD  '
end as empno, sum(sal)
from emp
group by mod(empno,2)

UNION ALL

select 'TOTAL' as empno, 
sum(sal)
from emp
```

Answer (score 0):

It is typically cheaper to reuse the result for the computation of a sum appended to the rows. For that purpose I suggest a [**CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html):

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT CASE WHEN empno % 2 = 0
            THEN 'EVEN '
            ELSE 'ODD  '
          END AS empno
        , sum(sal)::int AS sum_sal
   FROM   emp
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
SELECT *
FROM   cte

UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total ', sum(sum_sal)::bigint
FROM   cte;
```

Doesn't make a big difference for a query as trivial as in the example, but that's probably a simplification.